# Part of form to be transparent

Tags: gdi, transparent, device-compatibility

I have a Form which contains text and buttons.
I have to make part of the Form to be transparent while the other part remains the same.

Using BackColor and TransparencyKey same color
OR
set opacity.

Both above ways will affect the whole window. I need to change the part of(small portion)
of the form.  How can we achieve this ?.

Comment: Use, say, a Panel and set its BackColor property equal to the Form's TransparencyKey.  Or just draw the rectangle with the Paint event.

Comment: In both case, the forms back color prevails. Transparent color of part of the form is not working all.  I tried with backcolor and transparentkey...

Comment: The TransparencyKey needs to be something else than the form's BackColor of course.  Color.Fuchsia is a good choice.